# Should mailing address go on resume?

Tags: resume

I know it's similar to [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11945/is-it-ok-to-exclude-my-mailing-address-from-a-resume), but *should* a mail address (i.e. where you live) be included on a resume? In other words is there any down side to this?

Comment: Your clear distinction from [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11945/is-it-ok-to-exclude-my-mailing-address-from-a-resume) makes your question entirely asking for opinions, which is generally not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @CMW this is the second time you've made such a claim regarding opinions. In my opinion, unless something is a fact it is an opinion, and since it's impossible for a person to know the facts about every single work environment and every single person in it, in a sense the very nature of this site is opinion oriented. Navigating the work place is not a science.

Comment: @user16748 This is far from the second time I've tried to explain this. For your question there is no yes or no answer. Some may argue you should, some may argue you shouldn't. This site is not a forum for discussing pros and cons of these opinions. It may be worth taking a thorough look at [help/dont-ask] and [the explanation of good questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Your point that nobody knows everything about everything is excellent by the way. That's why we look for details to back opinions up, so we can trust that somebody actually knows.

Comment: @user16748 This [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) blog post might also be of interest.

Comment: My problem is that saying the question encourages subjective answers and putting the blame on the question is unfair. I believe the appropriate action would be to down vote an answer that is subjective, not vote to close the question. The question I ask is very concrete and very applicable to people trying to find a job,

Comment: and it elicites answers that are no more subjective than other popular questions on this site such as "Is it rude to leave an interview early if you have already made your decision?" or "How can I overcome “years of experience” requirements when applying to positions?" How can you say such questions are going to get more objective answers than one asking about the address on a resume?

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to give the recruiter or hiring manager any reasons to quick scan your resume and put it in the "No" pile.  Including your address probably won't trigger a "no", not including it might.  So you should include it.  If you're concerned about personal privacy, renting a post office box or signing up with a redelivery service might be an option.

Comment: Surely specifying a city would be sufficient to avoid getting a "no". Why would a hiring-manager require an exact postal address before the interview stage?

Comment: Why do you say that not including it might trigger a "no" response?

Comment: A city might be enough to avoid an immediate "no". People look at resumes with a set of expectations. If yours has something non-matching that can be seen in a 4-8 second scan, it is more likely to be set aside in favor of one that doesn't have the obvious mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

The one downside here is that if you are targeting a city you don't currently reside in.  If you are willing to cover the cost of traveling for interviews and relocating, then leaving it off will be a benefit.  Many companies don't have a budget for a relocation and will skip over a resume if it is not local.

I had this problem when trying to relocate to northern Virginia from the midwest and I got no traction with my resume until I took the address off.  Then I started getting all kinds of calls.  I was honest with recruiters that I was currently in the midwest, but was willing to pay my own relocation.  I did get a job there and did have to pay hotel/airfare for what amounted to a 30 minute interview as well as my own relocation.

In the United States anyway these expenses are tax deductible, both the job hunting expenses and the relocation (if over 50 miles).

Comment: That's one case where it might be helpful to leave it off.  I suggest addressing your willingness to self-relocate in the cover letter might be better, but it may be a wash.

Comment: I did that as well.  I think the wording I used was "relocating to the Washington DC area" in lieu of an address.

Answer (score 2):

Recruiters and initial screening HR people don't really need to know your mailing address to review your qualifications, and aren't likely to need to send you any mail correspondence.  Chances are you didn't mail them your resume either.  If you submitted it online, or via email, you can likely just use an email address for point of contact.

Phone number is optional, depending on how you expect to communicate with them.  If they want to set up a phone screen though, they will often just request the best number to reach you at via email.

You probably also want to include your region/city of residence though.  For instance, just "New York, NY", or "Mountain View, CA", as many places want a local candidate, but they don't need to know which neighborhood you live in.

At some point later if the process proceeds, they may request your full mailing address as part of a formal job application form they might use.  Or they'll just request it along with other info for the legal/internal parts of the hiring process.

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential downside to it, particularly if you put your resume out on a job site or farm it out into recruiters. Much like listing your phone number or email address, it gives people (possibly people well removed from those you originally submitted this to) the ability to contact you at will, and ties your name to that address, often in databases that will last a long time.

That said, there are upsides to it. Although, as I commented to @jwenting above, I've never received anything via mail from a company until the offer the letter, and generally not even that these days, there probably are still companies out there that do such things. And, as jwenting points out, it does establish where you live, which may influence hiring decisions. Lastly, you may just run into anal-retentive HR people who insist that there must be an address and reject any resume that doesn't have one.

Overall, I'd say it's a wash. The benefits are minor. The downsides are minor.

Answer (score -3):

How else are people going to get back to you? Consider the opposite, your resume contains no contact information whatsoever. HR reads it, thinks "wow, we'd like to talk to that bloke", then find they can't contact you. Missed opportunity.
Or more likely they'll just throw it away because they think you've something to hide about your condition, like maybe you're in prison or living in a homeless shelter while applying for a responsible position where you have to have a clean record.

Comment: I think the question is just "should my postal address be on my resume" not contact details completely. But your second paragraph is completely spot on (hence my +1!) - I would always put it on, even if just at town/state (or county for UK for example) level. It gives the recruiting company a feel for distance away from where the role may predominatly be based

Comment: I don't think I've ever had a company respond to me via mailing address. Everything has always been via the phone or email right up until (and not always then) the offer letter and supporting documents.

Comment: *How else are people going to get back to you?* By email? Otherwise, but rarely for a first contact, by phone. If it comes to the point when someone needs your address, they probably will ask you to provide/confirm it anyway. Even for a first phone interview, the candidate usually has to confirm or repeat the phone number beforehand in my experience. Nobody really relies on the resume for that.